# product link for Multistore search result

Tags: magento2, search

Current magento search results are not going to repeated store. It open at the current store. But the product is not included in current store. We would like to go the related store when click on the product.

Example:

1. Current store is `mainstore`. Search `rice` in search box.
2. In the `mainstore` there is no rice product. `rice` is only have in `store1`.
3. When click on the `rice`, it's showing the product under `mainstore`.

**Excepted Result**

When click on the `rice`, it's showing the product under `store1` instead of `mainstore`. The link should be `store1` link.

Is it possible to change the link of product in search result ?

Answer (score 0):

1. In admin, go to Product edit Page and switch to the store(store1 in your case) for which you want to make it available in Search
2. Change the **Visibility** to **Catalog,Search** for that store(store1 in your case) and Save the product
3. Now go to store(mainstore in your case) where you don't want it to be displayed in Search as well as Catalog
4. Change the **Visibility** to **Not visible individuall**y for that store(mainstore in your case) and Save the product
5. Run indexing, clear cache and test

Comment: Hi , we would like allow to search in every where. We would like to change the result link should direct to the related store.